# Complete a task before the timer runs out in python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I have 2 functions, one is a countdown timer and another is basically the function that I want to execute within the time period.

My code for the countdown timer is as follows:

```
def countdown(count):
   while count > 0:
       print(count)
       count -= 1
       time.sleep(1)
   return
```

My other function that I want to complete its execution before the timer runs out is as follows:

```
def solution(imat, painter):
nrows, ncols = imat.shape # gets the total number of rows and columns from a text file
for r in range(nrows): 
    for c in range(ncols):
        if imat[r,c] == 1: # checks if there is a 1 in any index (row and column) in the text file
            painter.paint('square',r, c, 1) # square is the method it uses to print, i.e  in blocks, and 1 is basically the size of the block that prints
```

My question now is that is it possible for me to run the solution function completely before the timer runs out?

I have tried to use `t1 = threading.Thread(target=countdown , args =(imat, painter))` in the solution function,, but it did not work. **The maximum value count can be set to is 20.**

The `painter.paint(...)` function runs at 160 commands, meaning there are a 160 1s in the text file, there is there is a way to reduce the number of commands that function takes to run?

Can the number of commands be reduced using threads?

All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you pass `target=countdown` rather than `target=solution`?

Comment: @PeterWood The reason I did that was because I thought that if I set the timer to let's say 10 seconds, and then when I start the thread in the solution function, the task could be completed in 10 seconds.

Comment: Additional files regarding this may be found here: [All the painter functions](https://gist.github.com/PrathamPatel/db928dd70b53189239b8e9cecd21d1b7)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Peter Wood is probably on the money in that you are targeting the countdown function, but passing arguments for the solution function in your threading code.

However, if you simply want to time your code, [this](https://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis) guide has some really good stuff in it on how to do so. I personally love the line_profiler as it gives you the execution time of each individual line.

Comment: Thank you for the guide, my aim is basically to speed the 'painter.paint' function so that it runs the least amount of commands to complete the task at hand. The text file contains 1s and 0s where the 1s print a pixel, meaning there are a 160 1s in the textfile which makes the commands run 160 times, is there a way to speed that up?

Comment: [All the painter functions](https://gist.github.com/PrathamPatel/db928dd70b53189239b8e9cecd21d1b7)